# PySpark: 'ResultIterable' object has no attribute 'request_tm'

Tags: pyspark

I use pyspark to deal with data. The data is as below:

```
8611060350280948828b33be803 4363    2017-10-01
8611060350280948828b33be803 4363    2017-10-02
4e5556e536714363b195eb8f88becbf8    365 2017-10-01
4e5556e536714363b195eb8f88becbf8    365 2017-10-02
4e5556e536714363b195eb8f88becbf8    365 2017-10-03
4e5556e536714363b195eb8f88becbf8    365 2017-10-04
```

I created a class to store these data. The codes are as following:

```
class LogInfo:
    def __init__(self, session_id, sku_id, request_tm):
        self.session_id = session_id
        self.sku_id = sku_id
        self.request_tm = request_tm
```

The dealing codes are as following:

```
from classFile import LogInfo
from pyspark import SparkContext, SparkConf

conf = SparkConf().setMaster("local[*]")
sc = SparkContext(conf=conf)
orgData = sc.textFile(<dataPath>)
readyData = orgData.map(lambda x: x.split('\t')).\
     filter(lambda x: x[0].strip() != "" and x[1].strip() != "" and x[2].strip() != "").\
     map(lambda x: LogInfo(x[0], x[1], x[2])).groupBy(lambda x: x.session_id).\
     filter(lambda x: len(x[1]) > 3).filter(lambda x: len(x[1]) < 20).\
     map(lambda x: x[1]).sortBy(lambda x:x.request_tm).map(lambda x: x.sku_id)
```

But the codes didn't work. The mistake information is as below:

```
     org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonException: Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "D:\spark-2.2.0-bin-hadoop2.7\spark-2.2.0-bin-
hadoop2.7\python\lib\pyspark.zip\pyspark\worker.py", line 177, in main
      File "D:\spark-2.2.0-bin-hadoop2.7\spark-2.2.0-bin-
hadoop2.7\python\lib\pyspark.zip\pyspark\worker.py", line 172, in process
      File "D:\spark-2.2.0-bin-hadoop2.7\spark-2.2.0-bin-
hadoop2.7\python\pyspark\rdd.py", line 2423, in pipeline_func
    return func(split, prev_func(split, iterator))
      File "D:\spark-2.2.0-bin-hadoop2.7\spark-2.2.0-bin-hadoop2.7\python\pyspark\rdd.py", line 2423, in pipeline_func
    return func(split, prev_func(split, iterator))
      File "D:\spark-2.2.0-bin-hadoop2.7\spark-2.2.0-bin-hadoop2.7\python\pyspark\rdd.py", line 2423, in pipeline_func
        return func(split, prev_func(split, iterator))
      File "D:\spark-2.2.0-bin-hadoop2.7\spark-2.2.0-bin-hadoop2.7\python\pyspark\rdd.py", line 346, in func
        return f(iterator)
      File "D:\spark-2.2.0-bin-hadoop2.7\spark-2.2.0-bin-hadoop2.7\python\pyspark\rdd.py", line 1041, in <lambda>
        return self.mapPartitions(lambda i: [sum(1 for _ in i)]).sum()
      File "D:\spark-2.2.0-bin-hadoop2.7\spark-2.2.0-bin-hadoop2.7\python\pyspark\rdd.py", line 1041, in <genexpr>
        return self.mapPartitions(lambda i: [sum(1 for _ in i)]).sum()
      File "D:\spark-2.2.0-bin-hadoop2.7\spark-2.2.0-bin-hadoop2.7\python\pyspark\rdd.py", line 2053, in <lambda>
        return self.map(lambda x: (f(x), x))
      File 
"D:<filePath>", line 15, in <lambda>
    map(lambda x: x[1]).sortBy(lambda x:x.request_tm).map(lambda x: x.sku_id)
AttributeError: 'ResultIterable' object has no attribute 'request_tm'
at 
org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRunner$$anon$1.read(PythonRDD.scala:193)
at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRunner$$anon$1.<init>
(PythonRDD.scala:234)
at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRunner.compute(PythonRDD.scala:152)
at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD.compute(PythonRDD.scala:63)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:323)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:287)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:87)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:108)
at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:335)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
[Stage 1:>                                                         (0 + 5) / 
10]17/12/01 17:54:15 WARN TaskSetManager: Lost task 3.0 in stage 1.0 (TID 13, localhost, executor driver): org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonException: 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\spark-2.2.0-bin-hadoop2.7\spark-2.2.0-bin-hadoop2.7\python\lib\pyspark.zip\pyspark\worker.py", line 177, in main
  File "D:\spark-2.2.0-bin-hadoop2.7\spark-2.2.0-bin-hadoop2.7\python\lib\pyspark.zip\pyspark\worker.py", line 172, in process
  File "D:\spark-2.2.0-bin-hadoop2.7\spark-2.2.0-bin-hadoop2.7\python\pyspark\rdd.py", line 2423, in pipeline_func
    return func(split, prev_func(split, iterator))
  File "D:\spark-2.2.0-bin-hadoop2.7\spark-2.2.0-bin-hadoop2.7\python\pyspark\rdd.py", line 2423, in pipeline_func
    return func(split, prev_func(split, iterator))
  File "D:\spark-2.2.0-bin-hadoop2.7\spark-2.2.0-bin-hadoop2.7\python\pyspark\rdd.py", line 2423, in pipeline_func
    return func(split, prev_func(split, iterator))
  File "D:\spark-2.2.0-bin-hadoop2.7\spark-2.2.0-bin-hadoop2.7\python\pyspark\rdd.py", line 346, in func
    return f(iterator)
  File "D:\spark-2.2.0-bin-hadoop2.7\spark-2.2.0-bin-hadoop2.7\python\pyspark\rdd.py", line 1041, in <lambda>
    return self.mapPartitions(lambda i: [sum(1 for _ in i)]).sum()
  File "D:\spark-2.2.0-bin-hadoop2.7\spark-2.2.0-bin-hadoop2.7\python\pyspark\rdd.py", line 1041, in <genexpr>
    return self.mapPartitions(lambda i: [sum(1 for _ in i)]).sum()
  File "D:\spark-2.2.0-bin-hadoop2.7\spark-2.2.0-bin-hadoop2.7\python\pyspark\rdd.py", line 2053, in <lambda>
    return self.map(lambda x: (f(x), x))
  File 
"D:<filePath>", line 15, in <lambda>
    map(lambda x: x[1]).sortBy(lambda x:x.request_tm).map(lambda x: x.sku_id)
AttributeError: 'ResultIterable' object has no attribute 'request_tm'
```

........

I think the main mistake information is as above. I could't figure out where I made mistake. Could anybody help?  Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to replace this:

```
map(lambda x: x[1])
```

with this:

```
flatMap(lambda x: list(x[1]))
```

Basically, after the groupBy, x[1] is a "Result**Iterable**" object so if you want to sort each element of it, you first need to flaten it.

Edit:
If you need a list of sku_id inside the rdd then:

```
 .map(lambda x: [y.sku_id for y in sorted(list(x[1]), key=lambda x: x.request_tm)])
```

Comment: It does work.  But actually I want to get a iterable result to build a model. So if I end up with:     'flatMap(lambda x: list(x[1])).sortBy(lambda x:x.request_tm).map(lambda x: x.sku_id)',  it shows an error when I build  model: 'java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.lang.Iterable'.  I tried replacing the whole sentence above with 'map(lambda x: sorted(list(x[1]), key=lambda x: x.request_tm).map(lambda x: x.sku_id))',  but it shows another error information: 'AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'map'.  How can I fix this problem? Thank you very much!

Comment: You need an iterable of which items? sku_id? Is this model part of spark? Can you give an example of using this model?

Comment: I would like to build a model with 'from pyspark.mllib.feature import Word2Vec' by sentences 'word2vec = Word2Vec(); 
model = word2vec.fit(data=readyData)'. I need an iterable of sku_id of each session_id, such as [['123', '456', '789'], ['321', '654', '987'], ['124', '345']]. Each sublist is an iterable of sku_id which occurs in the same session_id and sorted by the request_tm.